Produce -5 V with 250 mA max current limitation
How to produce -5 V with 250 mA max current limitation from a PSU with 12 V, -12 V and 5 V?
I could use a 7905 to produce -5 V, but then I can not find an IC of type Current-Limiting Power Distribution Switches that works also with negative voltages.
I have looked these ICs: TPS2046B, LP2952.

So you're looking for a different negative LDO, or a negative switch?  Would a negative LDO with an enable pin work? Like this: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps7a33.pdf?ts=1724082847841&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fpower-management%252Flinear-regulators-ldo%252Fproducts.html

TPS2046B is something completely different?

Is this for ATX computer supply? Why 250mA and why does it need limiting?

If your PSU is ATX computer supply do check if you can actually get 250 mA from -12V output. -12V is usually (very) low power as it isnt really needed in computers.

how much precision do you need on the 250mA?  do you need a switch ic?

Getting -5V from -12V at 250mA with a linear regulator means a lot of power dissipation -at least 1.75W.
I suppose you could follow up an LM7906 (and appropriate heatsink) with an LDO such as the (rather pricey) LT3090. The 7906 takes care of  wasting the bulk of the power and the LT3090 does fine regulation and current limiting.

Maybe you mean 7905 instead of 7906?

@AntonAndreev The  LM7906 is to allow 1V 'headroom' for the LT3090 to regulate down to (up to?) -5V.

You can build a crude negative regulator from refference+OpAmp+transistor.
Supply it from negative 12V.
A 2R2 shunt in 2n3906 current limitter should pass about 250mA maximum.
You can change the current limit with fine tune of shunt resistance (like 2R4 or so..).


Here is the datasheet for the LM337 adjustable negative voltage regulator.  Two of these in series will do exactly what you want.
-12 V source >> Current limiter >> Voltage regulator >> Output
The first one is the current limiter, configured as a 250 mA constant current output.  This will pass any current up to 250 mA.  Above this, its output voltage begins to sag to hold its output current at 250 mA.  This is how most linear current regulator circuits perform.
At 250 mA out, the current regulator output voltage will be approx. -9 V.  As above, trying to draw more current will cause this voltage to sag.  This is the input voltage to the voltage regulator.
The second one is the -5 V voltage regulator that gives a constant voltage output at a low source impedance.  With a 9 V input it will dissipate approx. 1 W at 250 mA.  Without a heatsink, that will burn your fingers but not destroy the part.  Any small heatsink, such as 1 square inch of bare aluminum, will improve this.  Note that the tab is electrically connected internally, so you cannot mount both regulators on the same heatsink without insulated mounting kits.
Page 9 of the datasheet has both circuits with their design equations.  The current-limit resistor Rs should be rated for at least 1 W.
LM337 datasheet

Reference Mouser of LM337 : 595-LM337KTTR

something like this perhaps:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Q1 and U1 have Collector and input on their respective heatsink tabs so they can easily share a heatsink

The 7905 heatsink dissipates less than 1.5 W worst case. How did you get 4 W?  At 250 mA, wouldn't that require 16 V across U1?

You're right, under 6V at 250mA
